# Migration from Fortis DynamicPlaceholders to Sitecore 9 DynamicPlaceholders

Tags: migration, dynamic-placeholder

I'm looking for migration solution from **Fortis DynamicPlaceholders** to **Sitecore 9 DynamicPlaceholders**.

**Fortis DynamicPlaceholder** looks like:

```
/main/content_container_ec526a7d-7838-4563-95a0-915bd2840dd8/grid_12_3f351279-e9a1-4c33-9b79-0defea684d18
```

**Sitecore 9 DynamicPlaceholder** looks like:

```
/main/content_container-{EC526A7D-7838-4563-95A0-915BD2840DD8}-0/grid_12-{3F351279-E9A1-4C33-9B79-0DEFEA684D18}-0
```

I need to update all content to **Sitecore 9 DynamicPlaceholders**

Maybe someone already did the same migration and has quick solution for it (Powershell script, aspx page)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the script I've used in the past:

```
# specify your path here. It is most likely be page templates and page content
$startPath = "/sitecore/content"
Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_;    

    Get-Rendering -Item $_  | ForEach-Object {
        $rendering = $_;
        $matches = [regex]::Matches($_.Placeholder,'(_[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-][0-9a-fA-F]{12})')

        if ($matches.Success) {
            Write-Host "Match found in item - [$($item.Paths.FullPath)]"
            Write-Host "Old Placeholder - [$($rendering.Placeholder)]"

            $newPlaceholder = $rendering.Placeholder

            $matches | ForEach-Object {
                $renderingId = $_.Value
                $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace($renderingId, "{$($renderingId.ToUpper())}-0")
            }

            $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace('{_', "-{")
            Write-Host "New Placeholder - [$($newPlaceholder)]"

            # comment following 2 lines if you don't want to do replacement, but want to have log of upcoming placeholder changes
            $rendering.Placeholder = $newPlaceholder
            Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $rendering 
        }
    }
}
```

It does changes only for the shared layout. In case you also need changes for Final Layout, then replace

```
Get-Rendering -Item $_  | ForEach-Object {
```

with

```
Get-Rendering -Item $_ -FinalLayout | ForEach-Object {
```

and

```
Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $rendering
```

with

```
Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $rendering -FinalLayout
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks @vzaverugo. One thing I found is that in my use of Fortis Dynamic Placeholders is that I had a case where I had multiple placeholders with the same name on one single rendering. In this case Fortis will append a suffix to the end of the placeholder key as an incremental seed value to ensure it is unique. So in my case I had to account for that. I modified your script and am putting that one as a separate answer.

Comment: @MikeM, thanks for pointing! this is a good case I haven't had in my configuration. Thanks for submitting your version here!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a modified version of @vzaverugo's script to account for when you have multiple placeholders with the same name in a single rendering. Fortis will append an incremental seed suffix. Sitecore 9 also has a concept of an incremental seed suffix. This modified script can account for that, as long as you setup your Sitecore 9 seeds to match the same increments that Fortis uses.

```
# specify your path here. It is most likely be page templates and page content
$startPath = "/sitecore/content"
Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_;    
    Get-Rendering -Item $_ -FinalLayout | ForEach-Object {
        $rendering = $_;
        $matches = [regex]::Matches($_.Placeholder,'(?<guid>_[\d\w]{8}\-(?:[\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12})(?<seed>_?\d?)')

        if ($matches.Success) {

            Write-Host "Match found in item - [$($item.Paths.FullPath)]"
            Write-Host "Old Placeholder - [$($rendering.Placeholder)]"

            $newPlaceholder = $rendering.Placeholder

            $matches | ForEach-Object {
                $match = $_
                $renderingId = $match.Value

                if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($match.Groups["seed"])))
                {
                    $seedSuffix = $match.Groups["seed"].ToString()
                    $seedValue = $seedSuffix.Trim("_")

                    # trim seed suffix off end 
                    $unsuffixedRenderingId = $renderingId.ToString().TrimEnd($seedSuffix)
                    # add seed value to end 
                    $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace($renderingId, "{$($unsuffixedRenderingId.ToUpper())}-$seedValue")
                }
                else
                {
                    $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace($renderingId, "{$($renderingId.ToUpper())}-0")
                }
            }

            $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace('{_', "-{")
            Write-Host "New Placeholder - [$($newPlaceholder)]"

            # comment following 2 lines if you don't want to do replacement, but want to have log of upcoming placeholder changes
            $rendering.Placeholder = $newPlaceholder
            Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $rendering -FinalLayout
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In above script there was a problem in below logic

```
$renderingId.ToString().TrimEnd($seedSuffix)
```

This will truncate the last three character if have same number before and after underscore like below example:

`$renderingId = "5c43afaf-958c-4d79-8395-41ad5aefd371_1"` and `$seedSuffix = "_1"` then output of `$renderingId.ToString().TrimEnd($seedSuffix)` will be `"5c43afaf-958c-4d79-8395-41ad5aefd37"`

I have updated the script to handle this issue which is working fine now.

```
# specify your path here. It is most likely be page templates and page content
$startPath = "/sitecore/content"
Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_;    
    Get-Rendering -Item $_ -FinalLayout | ForEach-Object {
        $rendering = $_;
        $matches = [regex]::Matches($_.Placeholder,'(?<guid>_[\d\w]{8}\-(?:[\d\w]{4}\-){3}[\d\w]{12})(?<seed>_?\d?)')

        if ($matches.Success) {

            Write-Host "Match found in item - [$($item.Paths.FullPath)]"
            Write-Host "Old Placeholder - [$($rendering.Placeholder)]"

            $newPlaceholder = $rendering.Placeholder

            $matches | ForEach-Object {
                $match = $_
                $renderingId = $match.Value

                if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($match.Groups["seed"])))
                {
                    $seedSuffix = $match.Groups["seed"].ToString()
                    $seedValue = $seedSuffix.Trim("_")

                    # trim seed suffix off end 
                    
                    if($renderingId.ToString().lastIndexOf($seedSuffix) -ge 0)
                    {
                        $unsuffixedRenderingId = $renderingId.ToString().Substring(0, $renderingId.ToString().lastIndexOf($seedSuffix))
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $unsuffixedRenderingId = $renderingId.ToString()
                    }
                    
                    # add seed value to end 
                    $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace($renderingId, "{$($unsuffixedRenderingId.ToUpper())}-$seedValue")
                }
                else
                {
                    $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace($renderingId, "{$($renderingId.ToUpper())}-0")
                }
            }

            $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace('{_', "-{")
            Write-Host "New Placeholder - [$($newPlaceholder)]"

            # comment following 2 lines if you don't want to do replacement, but want to have log of upcoming placeholder changes
            $rendering.Placeholder = $newPlaceholder
            Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $rendering -FinalLayout
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an aspx page for this which i used for migrating my project which can be found here https://github.com/jeroendegroot/MigrateDynamicPlaceholders It is been a while ago but all existing solutions i found then did not deal with final layouts and nested dynamic placeholders correctly.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, I think I may have come across your solution in my search for this problem. Thanks for sharing. I believe that vzaverugo's solution accounts for both final layouts and nested placeholders. Just, FYI, I also believe that your solution would need to be updated to account for the case where Fortis adds the incremental seed suffix to ensure a unique placeholder key inside of an individual rendering.