# Nested dynamic placeholder conversion

Tags: dynamic-placeholder

I am trying to convert the non-Fortis module of Dynamic Placeholders into the new in 9.x Sitecore Dynamic Placeholders with the format of PlaceholderName-{Rendering guid}-0 using C#.

I can easily update the single use from the main /main/placeholder_SCEXP1 but when it becomes nested, I lose the ability to update the nested ones such as

```
/main/placeholder_SCEXP1/column1/placholder2_SCEXP1/
and
/main/placeholder_SCEXP1/column1/placholder2_SCEXP2/
and
/main/placeholder_SCEXP2/column2/
```

etc.

so I need to write a recursive loop that would change all the

```
placeholder_SCEXP1 to placeholder-{C40B55F4-4986-4D8F-AE2A-D9A279CCE2C2}-1  
and then all the 
placeholder2_SCEXP1 to placeholder2-{72F55122-F279-4B5E-9E04-AF466A469316}-1 
and then the  
placeholder2_SCEXP2 to placeholder2-{72F55122-F279-4B5E-9E04-AF466A469316}-2
etc.
```

for all the dynamic placeholders on my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression in your power shell script to match the pattern and update the object. You need to use loop to traverse the content tree and update all the items where placeholders have been used.

This ticket may give you some idea.

[Migration from Fortis DynamicPlaceholders to Sitecore 9 DynamicPlaceholders](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10798/migration-from-fortis-dynamicplaceholders-to-sitecore-9-dynamicplaceholders/24070#24070)